# Setting Linux Permissions to Prevent other users from Deleting/Modifying files

Tags: linux, permissions

I know this is a noob question...
On centos6, I want to allow everyone to view directories and read files in some path while only the owner can modify or delete.
I cannot understand whu it does not work.
Here is a single file example of what I did:

```
# as user1:
vim x
chmod 744 x
-rwxr--r--  1 user1 user1 6 Oct  2 20:55 x

# as user2:
rm x
rm: remove write-protected regular file `x'? yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing a file actually changes the containing directory, so you need to prevent user 2 from changing the directory `x` lives in.

i.e. If the path to x is `/home/a/b/c/x` then `chmod go-w /home/a/b/c`

Comment: Thanks. I need to have 755 permission on the folder and 744 permission on the file. so two key points: #1 as you mentioned, #2: directories must have execute permissions in order to allow me to read their content.